# Can PostgreSQL tell me what configuration files it's using?

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I am having trouble with some changes I'm making to a configuration file. I think PostgreSQL is not using the ones I'm modifying. Is there any way to get postgres (maybe some environment variable) to tell me where I can find the various config files, including `pg_hba.conf` and `pg_ident.conf`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certainly:

```
SHOW hba_file;
SHOW ident_file;
```

or just

```
SHOW ALL;
```

:-)